# An elegant way to get the value from function

Tags: javascript, strings

I'm disturbed about the line `value.word = removeSpecialCharacters(value.word);`. Is there a elegant way to develop this line?

```
function checkWords() {
  var listOfWords = { word: "abc!!??deftest" };
  
  listOfWords.word = removeSpecialCharacters(listOfWords.word);
}

function removeSpecialCharacters(param) {
  return param.replace(/\s+/g, " ").replace(/[!?@#$%^&*()+-,.;:'"`\\|]/g, "").trim();
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, but consider if a whitelist of characters (eg `\w` and whatever others you permit) might work instead of a big list of special characters

Comment: Can you add more context about where this function is used and what it's meant to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the line you wrote. From just what you've written, I would suggest either of the following patterns:

```
var value = {
  word: removeSpecialCharacters("abc!!??deftest"),
};

function modifyWord(input) {
  let value = { word: removeSpecialCharacters(input.word) };
  ...
}
```

Comment: This is part of a website I'm developing, I've isolated this part to show you guys the exact point I'm trying to improve. So, I changed it to look more realistic and thanks for your answer, definitely is a better way to implement it.